# Traducir letras a números

Tags: javascript

Deseo crear un sistema que me permite traducir las letras de una palabra a un número. Para esto he creado un arreglo con todas las letras del abecedario, en teoría mi programa pregunta el nombre al usuario, y luego hace la conversión. Por ejemplo, `abc` sería `012`.

```
var abecedario=new Array(
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
    'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
    's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
);
var name = prompt("introduce tu nombre");
```

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Cual es el problema con el código ?

Comment: quiero que una palabra por ejemplo mi nombre steven se tradusca a numeros, que calcule la posicion de cada letra y me devuelva los numeros que lo componen basandose en el arreglo de mi abecedario

Comment: y cual es el problema???... fijate en los links que te pasaron arriba. No resolvemos problemas enteros, pero si podemos ayudarte si te trabas con algo en particular...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principio con un `array.indexOf();` deberias obtener la posicion de la letra que quieres.

```js
function rellenar(i,repetición,cifras)
{
  var devuelve=i+""
  while(devuelve.length<cifras){
    devuelve=repetición+devuelve
  }
  return devuelve
}

var abecedario=new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');
var nombre = prompt("introduce tu nombre");
var traducido = "";
for(i=0;i< nombre.length; i++){
    //alert(letras[i]);
    traducido += rellenar(abecedario.indexOf(nombre[i])+'',"0",2);
}
alert(traducido)
```

Comment: @G3l0 es mas sencillo que crear dos `for` o cambiar el array como en las dos otras respuestas.

Comment: es mas sencillo que OP muestre lo que intento y corrijamos sobre la base de eso ;)

Comment: gracias maestro, todavia que queda una duda, es necesario poner la var traducido vacia?

Comment: En javascript no es necesario declarar las variables, pero es recomendable (dependiendo del caso)

Comment: Con permiso, edito tu respuesta.

Comment: @ArtEze por supuesto :3

Comment: De paso, dejo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3Z-UPTJwg4

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta hacer una lista de letras, puedes usar su código restando el código de la primera letra (a) que sea relativa a ella.
Entendiendo que no quieres diferenciar mayúsculas y minúsculas, un ejemplo seria este:

```js
var palabra = window.prompt("Escribe una palabra.").toLowerCase();
var posicionRelativa="a".charCodeAt(0);
for (var i=0; i<palabra.length; i++){
 document.write(palabra.charCodeAt(i)-posicionRelativa);
 if (i<palabra.length-1) document.write(",");
}
```

Esto sirve para letras "anglosajonas", para el resto de caracteres tendrías que adaptar el código, y en ese caso si seria mejor crear un índice.

Answer (score -1):

Usa el array con pares clave -> valor

```
var abecedario= [];
abecedario['a'] = "0";
abecedario['b'] = "1";
abecedario['c'] = "2";
// asi hasta el final.
var name = prompt("introduce tu nombre");
var resultado = "";
for (var i = 0, len = name .length; i < len; i++) {
    resultado = resultado.concat(abecedario[name.charAt(i)]); 
}
```